# How to Implement MediaRouteButton in .Net Maui

Tags: android, maui

Looking for examples of how to Implement MediaRouteButton in .Net Maui 8.  I've looked at the docs on the Google SDK and it looks pretty straight forward., but not seeing  clear path to implement on Maui.    I have created a Custom handler and service to work with the MediaRouteButton.  It seems to sort of work.  It will detect Devices that match what the MediaSelector is looking for and it will provide a list.  However when the Cast button (MediaRouteButton) is clicked Internally the Button show attempt to show a dialogue box so the user can select the correct device.  But that is not publicly exposed. so Im kinda stuck for the moment.  I many end up creating my own but wnated to make sure I didn't miss anything.   Current code can be found at Github Repo in the (addingMediaRouter) branch https://github.com/Jricklefs/MauiApp3

**Custom Handler**

```
using AndroidX.MediaRouter.App;  <--- IT MediaRouteButton Was using Android.APP. 
using MauiApp3.CustomControls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
using static Android.Views.View;
using AndroidViews = Android.Views;
using AU = Android.Util;

namespace MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Handlers
{
    public partial class CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler : ViewHandler<CustomMediaRouteButton, MediaRouteButton>
    {
        public static IPropertyMapper<CustomMediaRouteButton, CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler> Mapper = new PropertyMapper<CustomMediaRouteButton, CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler>
        {
            // Add mappings here as needed
        };
        public CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler() : base(Mapper)
        {
        }
        protected override void ConnectHandler(MediaRouteButton platformView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
            // Perform any setup that requires the PlatformView to be present
            SetEnabled(VirtualView.IsEnabled);
        }
        protected override MediaRouteButton CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var mediaRouteButton = new MediaRouteButton(Context);
            mediaRouteButton.SetOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener());
            return mediaRouteButton;
        }

        private class CustomClickListener : Java.Lang.Object, AndroidViews.View.IOnClickListener
        {
            public void OnClick(AndroidViews.View? v)
            {
                //((MediaRouteButton)v).PerformClick();
                // Log the click event
                AU.Log.Debug("CustomMediaRouteButton", "Button clicked.");

                // Optionally perform additional actions here
                // If you want to show the dialog manually, you could invoke it here,
                // but only if it doesn't get automatically shown by the MediaRouteButton itself.

                // If the dialog does not automatically show, you can try to invoke it here manually.
                // However, if the dialog is automatically shown by the MediaRouteButton, you should
                // NOT call ShowDialog() here as it may interfere with the button's default behavior.
             
            }
        }

        private void OnMediaRouteButtonTouched(object sender, AndroidViews.View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle touch events here
            // e.Event gives you access to the MotionEvent
            var oo = "";
        }

        private void OnMediaRouteButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (VirtualView != null)
            {
                VirtualView.OnClicked();
            }
        }

        protected override void DisconnectHandler(MediaRouteButton platformView)
        {
            platformView.Touch -= OnMediaRouteButtonTouched;
            platformView.Click -= OnMediaRouteButtonClicked;
            base.DisconnectHandler(platformView);
        }


        public static void MapIsEnabled(CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler handler, CustomMediaRouteButton customMediaRouteButton)
        {
            handler.SetEnabled(customMediaRouteButton.IsEnabled);
        }



        private void SetEnabled(bool isEnabled)
        {
            //isEnabled = true;
            if (PlatformView != null)
            {
                PlatformView.Enabled = isEnabled;

                // Here you can adjust the visual state of the button,
                // like changing the opacity or text color, to indicate that it's disabled
                PlatformView.Alpha = isEnabled ? 1.0f : 0.5f;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateIsEnabled(bool isEnabled)
        {
            if (PlatformView != null)
            {
                PlatformView.Enabled = isEnabled;
                // Additional logic to update the visual state of the button
                PlatformView.Alpha = isEnabled ? 1.0f : 0.5f;

               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Device Discovery Service**

```
using Android.Content;
using AndroidX.MediaRouter.Media;
using AU = Android.Util;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.Gms.Cast;

namespace MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Services
{
    public class DeviceDiscoveryService : IDeviceDiscoveryService
    {
        private readonly MediaRouter _mediaRouter;
        private readonly MediaRouteSelector _mediaRouteSelector;
        private readonly MediaRouterCallback _mediaRouterCallback;
        private readonly List<string> _deviceNames = new List<string>();

        public event EventHandler DevicesChanged;
        public DeviceDiscoveryService()
        {
            // Use the static context from MainActivity
            var context = MainActivity.AppContext;

            _mediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .AddControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.CategoryForCast("My Reciver ID Here")) // Replace with your actual Cast receiver app ID.
            .Build();

            _mediaRouterCallback = new MediaRouterCallback(this);

            _mediaRouter = MediaRouter.GetInstance(context);
            _mediaRouter.AddCallback(_mediaRouteSelector, _mediaRouterCallback, MediaRouter.CallbackFlagRequestDiscovery);
        }

        // Implement device discovery logic here
        public  Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAvailableDevicesAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_deviceNames.AsEnumerable());
        }

        public async Task ConnectToDeviceAsync(string deviceName)
        {
            // Connect to the device
        }

        private class MediaRouterCallback : MediaRouter.Callback
        {
            private readonly DeviceDiscoveryService _service;

            public MediaRouterCallback(DeviceDiscoveryService service)
            {
                _service = service;
            }

            public override void OnRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
            {
                base.OnRouteAdded(router, route);
                _service._deviceNames.Add(route.Name);
                AU.Log.Debug("MainActivity", $"Route added: {route.Name}");
                // Notify subscribers that devices have changed
                _service.DevicesChanged?.Invoke(_service, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            public override void OnRouteRemoved(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
            {
                base.OnRouteRemoved(router, route);
                _service._deviceNames.Remove(route.Name);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Gms.Cast;
using Android.Gms.Cast.Framework;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using AndroidX.MediaRouter.Media;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Services;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MauiApp3
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        //private MediaRouter _mediaRouter;
        //private MediaRouteSelector _mediaRouteSelector;
        //private MyMediaRouterCallback _mediaRouterCallback;

        public static Context AppContext { get; private set; }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AppContext = ApplicationContext;

            InitializeCastContextAsync(ApplicationContext);

            DependencyService.Register<IDeviceDiscoveryService, DeviceDiscoveryService>();
            
        }

        private void InitializeCastContextAsync(Context context)
        {
            // Define the executor
            IExecutor executor = AsyncTask.ThreadPoolExecutor;

            // Call the asynchronous method to get the CastContext instance
            Android.Gms.Tasks.Task castContextTask = CastContext.GetSharedInstance(context, executor);

            
            // Add a continuation task to handle completion
            castContextTask.AddOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    // CastContext is initialized
                    var castContext = (CastContext)task.Result;
                    Log.Debug("MainActivity", "CastContext initialized successfully.");
     
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle initialization failure
                    Exception exception = task.Exception;
                    Log.Error("MainActivity", "Error initializing CastContext: " + exception);
                }
            }));

        }



        // Helper class to handle task completion
        public class OnCompleteListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
        {
            private readonly Action<Android.Gms.Tasks.Task> _onComplete;

            public OnCompleteListener(Action<Android.Gms.Tasks.Task> onComplete)
            {
                _onComplete = onComplete;
            }

            public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
            {
                _onComplete?.Invoke(task);
            }
        }





    }

}
```

**Cast Options Provider Class**

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Cast.Framework;
using Android.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace MauiApp3.Platforms.Android
{
    [Register("MauiApp3/CastOptionsProvider")]
    public class CastOptionsProvider : Java.Lang.Object, IOptionsProvider
    {
        public CastOptions GetCastOptions(Context appContext)
        {
            var options = new CastOptions.Builder()
                .SetReceiverApplicationId("My Reciever ID here")
                .Build();

            return options;
        }

        public IList<SessionProvider> GetAdditionalSessionProviders(Context appContext)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of what this is? I think you seem to be looking for something platform-specific https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/mediarouter/app/MediaRouteButton

Comment: @FreakyAli  I am looking at the MediaRouteButton of Android Casting ability.  I'm trying to implement the Casting button  into a demo app that I"m trying to POC.  Basically Implementing this https://developers.google.com/cast/       There are Nuget Pkgs that help out on this but there seems to be alot more leg work to try to get this working correctly  in Maui.

Comment: If you need MediaRouteButton, you will have to create a handler for it yourself there is no direct solution for it in any cross-platform frameworks I know of

Comment: @FreakyAli That is the path I'm going down,  I just about have it working but for some reason. When the MediaRouteButton is clicked. its native behaviour is to NOT call Clicked but to call ShowDialog internally to present the user with a list of Available Casting devices.  And this where I'm stuck.  The Show Dialog doesn't seem to do anything and I havn't figured out how t handle it. yet.  I would say I am aabout 85% there with implementing this.   I can provide you the code to where I'm at if you would like but its a lot of files.

Comment: I saw the issue and tried to implement that but also me stuck at the point that the Clicked event is not called. I have created a custom renderer for **MediaRouteButtonView** using AndroidX.MediaRouter.App.MediaRouteButton from the AndroidX package. The rendered is aiming to display a media route chooser dialog upon interaction, but the click event is failing to trigger.

Comment: @NikosBasdanis  I was am in the process of writing code to Set and Click even listner on the Button then hijack the response.   It will involve a tricky logic.  Also just posted my code so far. I left out the CustomMediaRouteButton  Class in the shared code but that part was pretty trival, with a little Trial and error.

Comment: Why don't you guys create a Github repo let me see if i can help

Comment: @FreakyAli I did, it the link is in the updated description,  Here it is again.   https://github.com/Jricklefs/MauiApp3  Grab the AddingMediaRouter Branch.

Comment: Its really going to come down to a few things based on where I'm currently at.  The ShowDialogue is not a public method.  and even if I get that to work I think I'll have to programatically set the casting device.  as I don't believe there is a Public method for that either because the MediaRouteButton was doing it internally.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into it first thing in the morning

Comment: @NikosBasdanis  I unless someone works some Android/java mojo, I think the only path forward is to Not try to call their click event.  You can Simlulate a click event on their button with ((MediaRouteButton)v).PerformClick();   but you run into a Null resource... etc error. same thing you get if you directly call the ShowDialog().  I was going to try to mediaRouteButton.SetOnClickListener(new CustomClickListener());  on the MediaRouteButton and then call another function,  to display the List of Devices. then when the user clicks a device, Programatically grab MediaRoute.Info and set it.

Comment: @NikosBasdanis I re-read your comment,  and I noticed that my CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler was using Android.App MediaRouteButton instead of Androidx MediaRouteButton. after make the change when the Button is clicked it automatically opens up a cast device Popuplist.  Currently its blank but work on it.

Comment: @JoeRicklefs ohh great to hear that, let me know if you figured out to implement that

Comment: @NikosBasdanis  I GOT IT!!!!     Turns out I was using a different MediaRoute in my Handler than I was in my DeviceDiscoveryService.   I Move the INitialization to my MainActivity then passed them down to the Handler and Device Discovery service and it just works.   I actually ended up removing a ton of Not usefull orphans at this point.  THe Google SDK3 pretty much does everything for you Casting.    Keep in mind that mine is using Custom Reciever.  But you can swap it out to use default easily.  WOrking Example is in the Repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the Solution:  This will get your code working with the MediaRouteButton.  Background the MediaRoutebutton does "Most" of the work for you.  After you initialize it and set up a few minor things, it will do the work of, "finding Devices", "filtering Devices by type",  "ManageConnections to the Device", "Create the Popup Device List"... It does most...  In this I don't go into what you can cast, because the requirements on this were to get this to work with a Custom Receiver.    If you go the Custom Receiver route you will have to host the HTML file on a Webserver and Register it with Google, because you will need the Custom App ID that google gives you.

You need Nugget Packages As of writhing this the Latest wouldn't work So I grabbed a previous version.
*Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Cast.Framework 121.2.0

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Cast 121.2.0

AndroidX  **Not 100% sure on the version.***

In your Xaml you'll need a custom Tag.

```
    <custom:CustomMediaRouteButton/>
```

and a reference at the top of your XAML page.

```
 xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:MauiApp3.CustomControls"
```

In your shared Code you'll Need a Class to associate with the new custom control.

```
namespace MauiApp3.CustomControls
{
    public class CustomMediaRouteButton : View
    {
    //Just Passing through
    }
}
```

In the Platform Specific (Android) in this case
Main Activity Looks like this:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Gms.Cast;
using Android.Gms.Cast.Framework;
using Android.Gms.Tasks;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using AndroidX.MediaRouter.Media;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Services;

namespace MauiApp3
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Maui.SplashTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Density)]
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static MediaRouter MediaRouterInstance { get; private set; }
        public static MediaRouteSelector MediaRouteSelectorInstance { get; private set; }
        //private MyMediaRouterCallback _mediaRouterCallback;

        public static Context AppContext { get; private set; }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            AppContext = ApplicationContext;

            InitializeCastContextAsync(AppContext);

            // Initialize MediaRouter and MediaRouteSelector
            MediaRouterInstance = MediaRouter.GetInstance(AppContext);
            MediaRouteSelectorInstance = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
                .AddControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.CategoryForCast("Custom APP ID"))
                .Build();

            DependencyService.Register<IDeviceDiscoveryService, DeviceDiscoveryService>();
        }

        private void InitializeCastContextAsync(Context context)
        {
            // Define the executor
            IExecutor executor = AsyncTask.ThreadPoolExecutor;

            // Call the asynchronous method to get the CastContext instance
            Android.Gms.Tasks.Task castContextTask = CastContext.GetSharedInstance(context, executor);

            // Add a continuation task to handle completion
            castContextTask.AddOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsSuccessful)
                {
                    // CastContext is initialized
                    var castContext = (CastContext)task.Result;
                    Log.Debug("MainActivity", "CastContext initialized successfully.");
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle initialization failure
                    Exception exception = task.Exception;
                    Log.Error("MainActivity", "Error initializing CastContext: " + exception);
                }
            }));
        }

        // Helper class to handle task completion
        public class OnCompleteListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
        {
            private readonly Action<Android.Gms.Tasks.Task> _onComplete;

            public OnCompleteListener(Action<Android.Gms.Tasks.Task> onComplete)
            {
                _onComplete = onComplete;
            }

            public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
            {
                _onComplete?.Invoke(task);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also Used a CastingOptionsProvider, not required but works.

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Cast.Framework;
using Android.Runtime;

namespace MauiApp3.Platforms.Android
{
    [Register("MauiApp3/CastOptionsProvider")]
    public class CastOptionsProvider : Java.Lang.Object, IOptionsProvider
    {
        public CastOptions GetCastOptions(Context appContext)
        {
            var options = new CastOptions.Builder()
                .SetReceiverApplicationId("Custom App ID")
                .Build();

            return options;
        }

        public IList<SessionProvider> GetAdditionalSessionProviders(Context appContext)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Add a Services Folder and drop in a Service in Platform Specific (android)
Here I added Overrides so I could walk through the devices as there were enabled.

```
using AndroidX.MediaRouter.Media;
using AU = Android.Util;

namespace MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Services
{
    public class DeviceDiscoveryService : IDeviceDiscoveryService
    {
        private readonly MediaRouter _mediaRouter;
        private readonly MediaRouteSelector _mediaRouteSelector;
        
        private readonly List<string> _deviceNames = new List<string>();

        //public event EventHandler DevicesChanged;
        public DeviceDiscoveryService()
        {
            _mediaRouter = MainActivity.MediaRouterInstance;
            _mediaRouteSelector = MainActivity.MediaRouteSelectorInstance;
            _mediaRouter.AddCallback(_mediaRouteSelector, new MediaRouterCallback(this), MediaRouter.CallbackFlagRequestDiscovery);
        }

        private class MediaRouterCallback : MediaRouter.Callback
        {
            private readonly DeviceDiscoveryService _service;

            public MediaRouterCallback(DeviceDiscoveryService service)
            {
                _service = service;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Leaving this so that you can see the Devices that were found.  Not required just Nice to see. Remove when you get it working the way you want. 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="router"></param>
            /// <param name="route"></param>
            public override void OnRouteAdded(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
            {
                base.OnRouteAdded(router, route);
                _service._deviceNames.Add(route.Name);
                AU.Log.Debug("MainActivity", $"Route added: {route.Name}");
                // Notify subscribers that devices have changed
               // _service.DevicesChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }

            public override void OnRouteRemoved(MediaRouter router, MediaRouter.RouteInfo route)
            {
                base.OnRouteRemoved(router, route);
                _service._deviceNames.Remove(route.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then Added a Handlers Folder in Platform Specific (Android)

```
using AndroidX.MediaRouter.App;
using MauiApp3.CustomControls;
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;

namespace MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Handlers
{
    public partial class CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler : ViewHandler<CustomMediaRouteButton, MediaRouteButton>
    {
        public static IPropertyMapper<CustomMediaRouteButton, CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler> Mapper = new PropertyMapper<CustomMediaRouteButton, CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler>
        {
            // Add mappings here as needed
        };
        public CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler() : base(Mapper)
        {
        }

        protected override MediaRouteButton CreatePlatformView()
        {
            var mediaRouteButton = new MediaRouteButton(Context);
            mediaRouteButton.RouteSelector = MainActivity.MediaRouteSelectorInstance;
            return mediaRouteButton;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Use this to Customize your Button for your app.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="isEnabled"></param>
        //private void SetEnabled(bool isEnabled)
        //{
        //    //isEnabled = true;
        //    if (PlatformView != null)
        //    {
        //        PlatformView.Enabled = isEnabled;
        //        // Here you can adjust the visual state of the button,
        //        // like changing the opacity or text color, to indicate that it's disabled
        //        PlatformView.Alpha = isEnabled ? 1.0f : 0.5f;
        //    }
        //}

        public void UpdateIsEnabled(bool isEnabled)
        {
            if (PlatformView != null)
            {
                PlatformView.Enabled = isEnabled;
                // Additional logic to update the visual state of the button
               // PlatformView.Alpha = isEnabled ? 1.0f : 0.5f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Android Manifest.
Added 2 lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.companyname.mauiapp3">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="MauiApp3">
        **<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME" android:value="MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" />**
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    **<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />**
    <uses-sdk />
</manifest>
```

The MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider needs to match the CastOptionsProvider  In my case  I had to register it So its actually this.   [Register("**MauiApp3/CastOptionsProvider**")]

And In the MauiProgram.cs file. Add the Hooks to wire the Platform stuff to the  custombutton you put in your XAML file.

```
#if ANDROID
using MauiApp3.CustomControls;
using MauiApp3.Platforms.Android.Handlers;
#endif

using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MauiApp3
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if ANDROID
            builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
                {
                    handlers.AddHandler<CustomMediaRouteButton, CustomMediaRouteButtonHandler>();
                });
#endif

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Thats it!!!

Comment: Great, good job!